# Read pictures from a map

Tags: java, debugging

I'm trying to read pictures from a map which is located in the same map as java files. It casts a NullPointerException. Note that the Kort class is working.

```
try {

        bildmapp = new File("bildmapp");
        bilder = bildmapp.listFiles();
        allCards = new Kort[bilder.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < bilder.length; i++) {

            allCards[i] = new Kort(new ImageIcon(bilder[i].getPath()), Kort.Status.DOLT);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gameFrame, "Error cause: " + e.getCause() + "\nArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException!"
                , "accessPicture Error!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gameFrame, "Error cause: " + e.getCause() + "\nNullPointerException!"
                , "accessPicture Error!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is probably in the `Kort` constructor, not in the code you've shown us here.

Comment: is bildmapp.listFiles() return the list of files?? If it is not then while creating Kort reference with bilder.length it will give NPE. Put a check before creating reference of Kort

Comment: The Kort constructor is working. Nothing wrong with it. I am sure about it.

Comment: Jigar - What do you mean with "Put a check" ?

Comment: Put e.printStackTrace() in both catch blocks, and then include the printed stack trace in your question

Comment: What is result of `bildmapp.exists()` and `bildmapp.isDirectory()`? If `bildmapp` doesn't contain location to directory `listFiles` will return `null` which means that `bilder.length` will throw NPE since `null` doesn't have `length` field.

Comment: `bildmapp.listFiles()` possibly returns null, because the directory "bildmapp" does not exists. Or more precisely exists, but in a different directory. When you create a File object using a relative path (`new File("bildmapp")`), the working directory is not necessarily the package with the source files.

Comment: The results of bildmapp.exist() and bildmapp.isDirectory() is False and false.

Comment: Im using IntelliJ and i just drag the map into the src map.

Comment: Try moving the "bildmapp" directory into the root of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`File#listFiles()` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--)

> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null.

Based on your comment

> The results of bildmapp.exist() and **bildmapp.isDirectory()** is False and false

it seems that this is situation mentioned in above documentation, which means that

```
bildmapp = new File("bildmapp");
bilder = bildmapp.listFiles();
```

will initialize `bilder` to `null`. Because of that

```
allCards = new Kort[bilder.length];
```

will throw NullPointerException because `bilder.length` would try to get `length` on `null`.

So to solve this problem you need to correct path to your directory in

`bildmapp = new File("bildmapp");`.

(I can't help you more since I don't know where your directory is or should be located. Maybe printing location which `bildmapp` is currently describing can help you determine which argument should be placed into `bildmapp = new File(...);` so try printing result of `bildmapp.getAbsolutePath()`).

Comment: Good answer!

The problem was solved by copying the directory bildmapp into the Memory/ directory. Now bildmapp.isDirectory(), bildmapp.exist() gives true and true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying class `Kort` work fine, then my guess will be your problem will be with your path, and `listFiles` is returning `null`. Trying to access property `length` on null it causing you null pointer exception

from java doc

> `public File[] listFiles()`
>
> Returns:  An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and
>   directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The
>   array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this
>   abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error
>   occurs.